# ¿Cuál es un sustantivo o frase de uso común que se refiere a las personas que duermen en la calle o al hombre sin hogar?

Tags: vocabulario, sustantivos

¿Cuál podría ser una palabra simple para los pobres que viven y duermen bajo las estrellas al aire libre?

- ¿un ***holgazán***?
- ¿una ***persona de la calle***?
- ¿un **vagabundo** pacífico y muy gentil?
- ¿mendigo que no necesariamente pide ni pide dinero?
- ¿un erizo callejero?
- ¿una persona transitoria?
- ¿una persona con ropa sucia que huele mal?

Comment: *Holgazán* no necesariamente se refiere a estas personas, más bien tiene que ver con la actitud hacia el trabajo que tiene una persona. Uno puede ser un *Holgazán*, y sin embargo, vivir en una mansión con todos los lujos y sin ninguna carencia. *Zángano* es más afin al sinificado de *Holgazán* que cualquier sustantivo apropiado para describir lo que preguntas, que se refiere más a una situación socioeconómica que a la actitud indiviudal hacia el trabajo. Por otro lado, ser un holgazán te puede llevar a esa situación... =)

Comment: En Chile se usó el eufemismo _indigentes_. Y como los eufemismos van cambiando rápidamente, ahora se les dice _personas en situación de calle_. (Acabo de notar que estoy repitiendo la respuesta de hlecuanda para México).

Answer (score 6):

En España, en los medios de comunicación, se usa "sin techo" o "[sintecho](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/sintecho-en-una-sola-palabra-564/)".

Answer (score 4):

En México también usamos "***sin techo***" o bien "***sin hogar***" aunque es frecuente también llamarles " ***... de la calle***".

Frecuentemente también se usa "***Menesteroso***" aunque este término está cayendo en desuso entre las nuevas generaciones, que prefieren los anglicismos "***Homeless***" o en ocasiones "***Hobo***".

[El término correcto según la RAE](https://dle.rae.es/indigencia) y el que se usa en comunicaciones oficiales del gobierno es, sin embargo

> ***Indigente***

o ***persona en situación de calle/indigencia***; ambos, en mi opinión, términos bastante neutros y sin ninguna connotación despectiva o discriminatoria, que reconocen la humanidad del individuo y se refieren sólo a la falta de medios para cubrir sus necesidades básicas y no a las consecuencias obvias o condición temporal de esta situación.

Answer (score 2):

Posible que es un poco anticuado, pero me ocurre el título de una canción popular mexicana del medio del siglo pasado: "Desamparada" que acaso se podría aplicar.

Comment: DLE tambien agrega "Abandonar, dejar sin amparo ni favor a alguien..."

Answer (score 2):

Otras que les faltaron decir y que por lo menos están relacionadas: **vagabundo**, **linyera**, **cartonero**, **atorrante** y **ciruja**.